# How do you check if multiple select elements (*not* a multiselect) have values?

Tags: jquery

I have a couple of select elements:

```
<select id='foo1'>
    <option value=''></option>
    <option value='foo'>asdf</option>
    <option value='bar'>asdfasdf</option>
</select>

<select id='foo2'>
    <option value=''></option>
    <option value='foo'>asdf</option>
    <option value='bar'>asdfasdf</option>
</select>

<select id='foo3'>
    <option value=''></option>
    <option value='foo'>asdf</option>
    <option value='bar'>asdfasdf</option>
</select>
```

Is there an easy way to check if each one has any value selected that is not the first empty value without using a loop or the jQuery each method? I could do it with loops, but I'd rather use a single selector.

```
$("[id^=foo]").val();
```

Sadly doesn't work. Is there any easy way to do this with jQuery in 1 line of code, or do I have to write a loop or use an .each?

Comment: each of them has value selected... what do you mean "selected"

Comment: OP, which is unselected?

Comment: My mistake, I've updated the question. "selected" means any option that is not the first empty one.

Comment: Use a class on each of the `<select>` and reference that. `$(".selectClass").each(function(){  });` Then inside the each function check to see if the value is empty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use that :

```
if($('[id^=foo] [value=""]:selected').length === 0)
    //All selects have a value
```

```js
$('select').change(function(){
    if($('[id^=foo] [value=""]:selected').length === 0)
        alert('all are selected');
    else
        alert('At least one is not selected');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id='foo1'>
    <option value=''></option>
    <option value='foo'>asdf</option>
    <option value='bar'>asdfasdf</option>
</select>

<select id='foo2'>
    <option value=''></option>
    <option value='foo'>asdf</option>
    <option value='bar'>asdfasdf</option>
</select>

<select id='foo3'>
    <option value=''></option>
    <option value='foo'>asdf</option>
    <option value='bar'>asdfasdf</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Great! A similar answer was posted below, but this one can work with as many or as few select elements as I need, without having to adjust the code.

Answer (score 2):

You could do it this way by filtering out and checking its `length` property.

```
if($('[id^=foo]').filter(function(){ return $(this).val() !== '' }).length == 3){
   // every select has a value
} else  { 
   // at least one select doesn't have a value
}
```

Answer (score -3):

```
$("select").each(function(){
    var Sel = $(this).attr("id");
    if($(this).val()==""){
        alert("select "+ Sel +" has no value!");
    }
    else{
         alert("select "+ Sel +" has a value!");
    }
});
```